# readdir doesn't work properly in linux system

Tags: c++, linux, file, directory, readdir

**EDITED with full code :**

```
int filename_extract(){
DIR *pDIR;
struct dirent *entry;
string file;

     try{
         if((pDIR=opendir("/home/xxx/Documents/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/allen-p/all_documents")) != NULL){

             while((entry = readdir(pDIR))!=NULL){

                 if( strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0 ){
                    file = entry->d_name;
                    cout << file << "        ";    // Doesn't print anything                    
                }
        }
        closedir(pDIR);
    }
}catch(exception &e){
    cout << "Error occured in filename_extract function " << e.what() << endl;
}

    return 0;
}
```

But entry->d_name isn't storing any of the file names from the directory and `/home/xxx/Documents/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/allen-p/all_documents` folder contain files of plain text document type namely:

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
....
648.
```

Why is it not working properly and where I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: What have you tried as far as debugging? Have you tried commenting out your `if` so as to print all filenames, including "." and ".."?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/klONt5). Show a complete program.

Comment: yes i debugged the code and checked too apart from printing, nothing is getting stored in `entry->d_name` and it's first character is "." and I tried removing the 'if' condition, even it gives the same result.

Comment: @n.m. Yes it's working for me too with folders,i.e., if I give my path as `/home/xxx/Documents/enron_mail_20110402/maildir/allen-p`, it's returning all the folder names contained in the path given.But it's not working if you have just files (eg. plaintext file type as in my case)

Comment: @annunarcist "." is a valid directory entry name, and, in fact, will likely be the first entry in any directory...

Comment: The code posted looks reasonable - though you should at least print an error if opendir() returns NULL. Have you tried it on other folders, e.g. /tmp ? I can *guarantee* you that readdir() works fine, so the error is elsewhere. If you don't figure it out, post a **complete** example that we can compile and try.

Comment: @twalberg Oh yes, after two iterations(one for "." and one for ".."), I'm able to get the filenames stored in `file` but in random order (not in the order I see from the folder) and is it supposed to be like that? And what does "." & ".." mean?? Why are they stored as first characters.

Comment: @annunarcist Files are not stored in any particular order in the directory - any sorting you're accustomed to is done by `ls` or whatever else you use to look at the directory. The "." entry references the directory itself and ".." references its parent directory - which is how things like `cd ..` or `./someprogram` work... Normally, when you `mkdir`, the "." and ".." entries are added automatically, and for somewhat obvious reasons never go away, so they stay the first two entries...

Comment: @twalberg But what if there are both folders & files within a folder. How can we ignore folder names & get only filenames that we are interested in (or the other way around)?

Comment: @annunarcist for each directory entry you process, you have to check whether it is a file or something else. You can find that out using `stat()` or some other library calls.